# Mips Output syscall

Tags: mips, system-calls, spim

```
li $s5, 2
add $a0, $s5, $0
li $v0, 4
syscall
```

Why system out is (null) in spim ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are trying to print an int, but the system call code you are providing stands for "print string".

As you have no label called `2` (hence no string starting at address of label `2`), the console prints out `(null)`.

Try this

```
li $a0, 2 #integer to be printed
li $v0, 1 #system call code 1: print_int
syscall
```

Now it should print 2

Check out this [table](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html) for syscall op codes.